# H2 Database - mapping between Java's OffsetDateTime and h2 type

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp, h2, sql-timestamp

I am using [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/) for unit tests.

According to the official H2 documentation, there is no mapping between Java's `OffsetDateTime` and h2 data types (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` maps to java's H2 `TimestampWithTimezone` type, which is not what I need).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is true that a plain `getObject(int columnIndex)` will return an `org.h2.api.TimestampWithTimeZone` object, using `getObject(int columnIndex, Class<T> type)` to return a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` seems to work fine for me using H2 version 1.4.196:

```java
package h2test;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class H2testMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test")) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, TWTZ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)");
            st.execute("INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TWTZ) VALUES (1, '1981-02-03 19:20:21-02:00')");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT TWTZ FROM TEST WHERE ID=1");
            rs.next();
            OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class);
            System.out.println(odt.getClass().getName());  // java.time.OffsetDateTime
            System.out.println(odt.toString());  // 1981-02-03T19:20:21-02:00
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

}
```